# Reading data from InputBox and insert into 1-D Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, listbox

I'm trying to insert numbers from InbutBox and save them into array to display them later into listbox

my Vb.net Code

```
Dim NumArray() As Double 
Dim ii As Integer = 10
    For ii = 0 To ii -1 
        NumArray = InputBox("Insert Number "+ii+"value", "Data Insertion", , , )
    Next

For ii = 0 To 10 -1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(NumArray(ii))
Next
```

It's not working. What's wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that you should be doing, especially if you want to continue to use an InputBox.

First you need to validate that the value entered is a valid Double. You can do this by implementing the [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Next, rather than trying to input the values into an array, simple add them to directly to your control.

Finally, I wanted to point out that your For/Next loop would never execute. The reason is because first, you overwrite the value of `ii` from 10 to 0. Next you try to iterate from 0 to -1, but never change the step of the loop to iterate backwards; by default the step of a For/Next loop is +1. So what happens is your loop starts at 0, check if it is less than -1, realizes that it isn't, and nothing happens.

Here is an example of implementing the suggestions:

```
'Placeholder variables for the For/Next loop
Dim dbl_value As Double
Dim str_value As String

'Loop from 1-10
For ii As Integer = 1 To 10
    'Prompt for the currently iterated index's value
    str_value = InputBox("Insert number " & ii & " value", "Data Insertion")

    'Loop until the user enteres a valid Double
    Do Until Double.TryParse(str_value, dbl_value)
        'Inform the user that then did not follow instructions and re-prompt for a valid Double
        str_value = InputBox("That was not a valid Double. Please insert number " & ii & " value", "Data Insertion")
    Loop

    'Add the Double value to the ListBox
    ListBox1.Items.Add(dbl_value)
Next
```

Comment: thanks very much for explanation it was very helpfull , Accepted

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

```
Dim ii As Integer = 10
Dim NumArray(ii - 1) As Double 
For i As integer = 0 To ii -1 
    NumArray(i) = InputBox("Insert Number " + i + "value", "Data Insertion", , , )
Next

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(NumArray)
```

and:

```
Dim ii As Integer = 10
Dim NumArray As New List(Of Double)
For i As Integer = 0 To ii -1 
    Dim input As Integer = InputBox("Insert Number "+ii+"value", "Data Insertion", , , )
    NumArray.Add(input)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(input)
Next
```

and

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(i) InputBox("Insert Number " + i + "value", "Data Insertion", , , )).ToArray())
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that your code would not compile with Option Strict on. Also, there is no data validation, which is simply foolish when using an InputBox to prompt for something other than a String value. Finally, in your first two examples you store the value into an array first when the values should be directly added into the control. Plus, in your first example you use AddRange, but in your second example you use Add. If you're going to add them to a collection first, its best to only use AddRange like you did in the first example.

Comment: that is so working , thank for help , i'm trying them all , thanks